Function values in columns rather then rows with numerica-tables
Package numerica-tables helps create of multi-column tables of mathematical function values, the package arranges values  on rows like in this simple example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numerica}
\usepackage{numerica-tables}
\begin{document}

\tabulate[rvar=x,rstep=0.2,rstop=1]
{ \sin x }[x=0]

\end{document}

I looked  the package manual and couldn't find any example of table with values arranged in columns, Is there any help to create tables of function values like the image with this package?


This is a reasonable request which the numerica-tables package does not at present meet easily, but it is possible to get the result you want in a roundabout way:
\constants{ x=0 }
\tabulate[rdata={\sin x},rverb=1,rhead=x,
   cvar=y,cstep=0.2,cstop=1,chround=1]
   { \sin y }[y=0.2]


You might like to add ,chnudge=18 after chround=1 and [*] after the closing square bracket on the last line to add the final touches.
